# ABP 4.0 Blazor - Overriding Identity Views

Tags: abp

I am trying out ABP 4.0 using the Blazor UI and want to override the built-in view for User Management.
Inspecting the source code I found the UserManagement.razor file which has the route of "/identity/users" - this matches the view that I want to override.

I have (I believe) followed the steps listed at: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Blazor/Customization-Overriding-Components. However when running the site, I still get the standard, built-in user list.

Pages/Identity/UserManagement.razor (within my wwwroot folder):

```
@inherits Volo.Abp.Identity.Blazor.Pages.Identity.UserManagement
<h2>This is not the standard page</h2>
```

Pages/Identity/UserManagement.razor.cs

```
using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection;

namespace BlazorDemo.Blazor.Pages.Identity
{
    [ExposeServices(typeof(UserManagement))]
    [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
    public partial class UserManagement
    {
    }
}
```

Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a diffent name for your own component, like `MyUserManagement.razor`. Otherwise, compoiler can not distinguish the classes. For example,

```cs
using Volo.Abp.DependencyInjection;

namespace BlazorDemo.Blazor.Pages.Identity
{
    [ExposeServices(typeof(UserManagement))] //MUST BE Volo.Abp.Identity.Blazor.Pages.Identity.UserManagement
    [Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
    public partial class UserManagement
    {
    }
}
```

Here, `ExposeServices` exposes itself (your class) instead of the `Volo.Abp.Identity.Blazor.Pages.Identity.UserManagement`. If you rename your component to `MyUserManagement` than you don't make such mistakes :)